# In law of large numbers, when does the limit exist if the summands are still iid but changes with the sample size $n$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I think the tittle summarises the question, but I'll detail below.

Th laws of large numbers deal with the connvergence in probability or almost surely of the average/mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i, X_i \sim X$ are iid. However, $X_i$ are not allowed to depend on $n.$

Now say we replace $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ by $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^{(n)}_i,  X^{(n)}_i \sim Z_n,?$ So this time, we make sure the summands under the sigma notation are still iid, but as the sample size $n$ changes, the summands also change depending on $n$, and the summands $X^{(n)}_i \sim Z_n \forall n \ge 1.$

It's clear that the limit may not exist and will largely depend on how $Z_n$ changes with $n.$ But what if in addition, we assume that $Z_n \to_{p} Z$ and/or that $EZ_n \to \mu?$ In  these cases can we say something about the limit
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^{(n)}_i?$ Some pointers would be great, an answer would be nice too!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's LLN for arrays. E.g., the first link in google: https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~xshi/econ715/Lecture_9_local_power.pdf

Comment: As long as the $X_i^(n)$ tend to a common mean and have controlled variance, the CLT holds. See the Lindeberg-Feller CLT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition